# How much cash should I take for wild camping the West Highland Way?

Tags: planning, money, payment-cards, hiking, scotland

I will go hiking / wild camping the West Highland Way (Scotland) with one partner for about 12.5 days. I will buy the flights in advance and I know how much I have to have with me for trains. I want to buy food in local stores so that I don't have to take too much weight with me. However, I have no idea how much paper money I should take with me. (I will also take my VISA card with me, but I don't know if local supermarkets will accept it.)

What would you suggest?

Comment: Given that this is primarily opinion based and is likely to be put on hold as such I would suggest as much as you think you need.

Comment: The problem is I have no idea how much I need. In Germany, I pay about 3.5 Euro / day for food. I will not be able to live that cheap in Scotland, I guess. I have no idea if food is generally more expensive there. I would like to hear some prices I could orient myself on. (and the sub-question if VISA is generally accepted in Scotland is objective, isn't it?)

Comment: The problem is without a list of what you intend to buy, in what quantities, and the required quality of a product neither do we.

Comment: But about 80,000 people go the WHW per year. There have to be some figures of experience. Of course, it will not fit 100% for me. I don't expect that. (and again, don't forget my VISA sub-question)

Comment: Wonderful.  Some eat meat others don't, some what organically grass fed beef others don't care.  Some are allergic to gluten others are not.  Some don't need chocolate bars others do.  You see where I am going with this?  Unless you can provide what exactly you will be needing, how much and when there is really no way to answer the question.

Comment: Zero.  There are no fees to hike the wild camping way and the route is short enough to carry all food on your back from the start.

Comment: This question probably fits better on [Outdoors.SE].

Comment: @gerrit Yes, I think so too. Can somebody please move it?

Comment: Are you UK based?

Comment: @DJClayworth: No, I'm from Germany.

Comment: @moose, if you have a Euro denominated VISA card that works as a debit card, you'll be fine in the local supermarkets.  So you're talking about pocket money and 10 - 20 pounds should be fine.  Be sure to spend the Scottish pounds before you leave.

Comment: @GayotFow Wait a second ... scottish pounds? I though England / Scottland / Wales had the same currency?

Comment: @moose, think again.  It's part of the Scotland experience.  Just spend them before you leave :)

Comment: @moose Slight joke. Scotland has the same currency as England, but it does print its own banknotes. They are theoretically just as usable as the English notes, but people are not used to them and sometimes refuse them outside Scotland. English-printed notes are completely acceptable in Scotland.

Comment: Flagged for migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never walked the WHW, but I have spent plenty of time in rural Scotland, *Most* stores in Scotland, even in villages, will take credit cards. However most is not all, and you will probably find some that won't. If you are paying for campsites rather than camping wild, or if you are planning on the odd night at a B&B, some will probably only take cash. Even those that take cards will be much happier if you offer them cash. Scottish businesses really like it when they don't have to pay transaction fees. I would recommend keeping a stock of cash on hand sufficient for your next couple of purchases. Even if you aren't intending to buy accommodation, you might like to keep enough cash to pay for a night in a B&B in case of damage to your tent, hurricanes etc.

On the upside there are ATMs at reasonably frequent intervals on the WHW i.e. you will pass one most days, but it's not guaranteed that any given village will have one.. Almost all are private rather than bank machines, so you will pay a fee for withdrawal, as well as any charges from your bank and exchange fees.You should probably check that your card will work in them.

You can invariably use cards for train fares, even if you get on at a small station and pay on the train.

I'm not going to give a figure for how much cash you actually need. Food isn't going to be too different from elsewhere in Europe, and only you know what you are going to want to buy.